# Decoding the data received from gigabit ethernet port with Python

Tags: python, udp, port, decode, ethernet

I want to connect to a detector and receive image data. After working with Wireshark software, I realized that I should use protocol UDP. I wrote the following code in Python and got the data.
The received data sample is as follows:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "1.1.1.1" #IP
UDP_PORT = 123  #port

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048)
    print("recived message: %s" % data)
```

Output:

```
data1 =b'\x83\xa4A\xd2\x01\x00\x00\x00\x12\x05\xf3\x04.\x04\xb7\x04#\x05Y\x04\x9f\x05\xf4\x046\x05\x89\x04\x1b\x08\x9b\x05^\x05\xb7\x04G\x05\x04\x04\xc7\x05\\\x05\xc8\x04$\x06:\x05\xf1\x05\x90\x06\x1f\x05w\x05\x8d\x05\x15\x05P\x06\x19\x05\x8a\x06e\x06\xfd\x05w\x06f\x05\x1f\x05!\x06\xed\x04\xb8\x06\xeb\x05\xd9\x05\x13\x06{\x05\x01\x07i\x07\xed\x07f\x08\x9c\x08\x80\x08\\\x08A\x08w\x08y\x089\x08<\x08\x11\x08m\x08\x1f\x08M\x07$\x08\xc5\x07\xe5\x08\xd9\x08q\x07\x7f\x08^\x08i\x08S\x08\xa7\x07.\t\x15\x08\x1d\x08\xae\x08\x8e\x07E\x08\xdc\x07\xf3\x061\t\xcd\x07\xe8\x08Y\x08\x00\x08\xb5\x08\xa3\x08\t\tt\x08q\x08w\t\r\t\xbd\x08p\x08\xfb\x08\xc5\x08_\x08\xe4\x07\n\x08/\x08\xf4\x07\xdc\x07#\x08\x99\x08\xf3\x07\xc5\x07Y\t\r\x08\xdd\x08\x91\x08\x91\x07\x91\x07?\x08\xd8\x08J\x08_\x08E\x08\xf9\x07\x1f\x08L\x08\xff\x07\xd7\x07M\x08<\x08\xdf\x08\x89\x075\tw\x08\x89\x08\x15\t......................
```

But I don't know how to decode the data. Wireshark itself does this. But I don't know how to decode with Python.

```
7c 10 c9 20 e3 31 da 55 aa 55 aa 01 08 00 45 00 05 dc 00 00 00 00 80 11 a9 97 c0 a8 05 15 c0 a8 05 14 15 be 15 be 05 c8 00 00
```

I use the following code, but it returns meaningless data.

```
data.decode("utf-16")
```

My first question is, how can I get from the primary data to the data that Wireshark decodes with Python?
And my second question is: How should I get from this data to the data I want, which are approximately numbers between 1000 and 10000? A number for each pixel, which is the sequence of received data, in the row and column of forming an image.

Comment: The structure of the data and the way you need to decode the data and extract the information you want depends on the application protocol used for the communication. If you are lucky then there are existing implementations to parse the protocol data, otherwise you need to implement it yourself based on some specification you either have or need to reverse engineer. Nothing is known about the specific protocol used here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The side that sends the data is an electronic board (detector). How can I find out how to decode it?
How can I convert the received data into data like Wireshark?

Comment: Wireshark can decoee various protocols but not all. If Wireshark can decode this then check, as what kind of application protocol this is detected by Wireshark and then follow the specification of the relevant protocol in your own code.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It uses protocol UDP. Does that mean I have to replace all the characters of \x with space?

Comment: If you just want the hex bytes of the `data` byte string, `print(data.hex(sep=' '))`

Comment: @MarkTolonen thank you. In the next step, how should I convert to decimal? I used int(hex_string,16) but there was an error.

Comment: That depends on what the data represents. It’s not simply encoded text, so a simple .decode() won’t do it.